# Using \PSTricks in Scientific Workplace

Tags: pstricks, scientific-workplace

Is there any way to use graphs generated with PSTricks in Scientific Workplace (which uses MikTeX to produce pdf files)?

Comment: If you graphs are individual files, you can obtain them as   pdf images, which can be included with `\includegraphics`. I suppose Scientific Workplace has tools to insert this code.